# Integrating tabletop.js with d3.js?

Tags: json, d3.js, google-sheets, tabletop.js

I want to reference a google spreadsheet using tabletop for for the data in my d3 visualization. The best solution I can come up with is this, but I know that it's not quite right.

```
window.onload = function() { init() };

var public_spreadsheet_url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?hl=en_US&hl=en_US&key=0AmYzu_s7QHsmdDNZUzRlYldnWTZCLXdrMXlYQzVxSFE&output=html';

function init() {
  Tabletop.init( { key: public_spreadsheet_url,
                 callback: showInfo,
                 simpleSheet: true } )
}

d3.json("showInfo", function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The data comes as an array already (see output below); and so there is no need to apply `d3.json`. You can start using the array for your d3 visualization right away.

```
window.onload = function() { init() };
var public_spreadsheet_url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?hl=en_US&hl=en_US&key=0AmYzu_s7QHsmdDNZUzRlYldnWTZCLXdrMXlYQzVxSFE&output=html";
function init() {
    Tabletop.init( { key: public_spreadsheet_url,
        callback: showInfo,
        simpleSheet: true } )
}
function showInfo(rows) {
    console.log(rows);
    // build your d3 vis here..
}
```

[image]